# Finding attribute value of some unspecified ancestor using Xpath

Tags: xpath

I would like to find an XPath expression to select nodes, whose attribute 'a' value exists and is concatenation of their attribute 'b' and value of 'a' of the FIRST ancestor, for which attribute 'a' exists, or such nodes, that they are first in the hierarchy, which have attribute 'a'.

```
<A a='TOWN/'>
 <B>
  <C a='TOWN/STREET' b='STREET'>
    <D a='TOWN/STREET' b='STREET'>
    <E a='TOWN/STREET/HOUSE' b='STREET'></E>
    <F a='TOWN/STREET/HOUSE' b='HOUSE'>
     <G a='TOWN/STREET/HOUSE' b='HOUSE' ></G>
    </F>
   </D>
  </C>
 </B>
</A>
```

The Xpath should only pick Elements A, C and F
I tried `\\*[(@a = concat(ancestor::*[@a][1]/@a,'/',@b)) or (not(ancestor::*[@a])]`, but it does not work as intended.

Can you please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First, you're using backslashes instead of slashes in the beginning of your query. Then, your input is inconsistent (or copy&paste error?), there is a slash in the end in `//A/@a`, but not in the other `@a` attributes. When removing this (so `<A a='TOWN'>...</A>`, this XPath query will do what you want:

```
//*[@a = concat(ancestor::*[@a][1]/@a, '/', @b) or not(ancestor::*[@a])]
```

If you cannot change the input, check for versions both adding the slash and not adding it:

```
//*[@a = concat(ancestor::*[@a][1]/@a, '/', @b) or @a = concat(ancestor::*[@a][1]/@a, @b) or not(ancestor::*[@a])]
```

Comment: Ok beets me be several minutes. +1

Comment: Thank you, it was typo indeed.

Comment: If it works you should "accept" it, so others having a similar problem or answering questions can see the question is solved.